# Extracting data from complex JSON structure in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
   "position":[
      {
         "top":[
            42,
            12
         ]
      },
      {
         "middle":[
            10,
            15
         ]
      },
      {
         "bottom":[
            5,
            201
         ]
      },
      {
         "axis":[
            {
               "X":[
                  901,
                  51,
                  67
               ]
            },
            {
               "Y":[
                  1474186,
                  561647
               ]
            },
            {
               "Z":[
                  911,
                  1296501
               ]
            },
            15,
            20
         ]
      }
   ],
   "validated":true,
   "metadata":{
      "uri":"/data/complex/",
      "session":[
         1818,
         14
      ],
      "private":false
   },
   "vists":0,
   "ok":true,
   "data":{
      "10":{
         "title":"Alpha",
         "author":"Justin X. Ample",
         "cover":"/f48hf58.tiff"
      },
      "901":{
         "title":"Tau",
         "author":"Felina Blank",
         "cover":"/45trthrref.tiff"
      }
   },
   "live":null
}
```

From this data I want to display a list like this:

```
Alpha, Justin X. Ample
Tau, Felina Blank
```

Note that the keys (in my example, 10 and 901), are not predictable. So I want to somehow create an object that represents the "data" structure and iterate over it to get the title and author for each entry.

With a basic JSON structure I had success with something like this (using JSON.NET):

```
public class Foo
    {
        public int bar { get; set; }
        public string baz { get; set; }
        public string quxx { get; set; }
    }

...

// json = {"bar": 1, "baz":"two", "quxx":"three"}
var result = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Foo>(json);

return result.baz // "two"
```

But I can't figure out what I need to do to make it work with a complex structure.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2012, get [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=275131). It has a feature called "Paste JSON as class" which will generate a C# class from the JSON that is in the clipboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
var result = jObj["data"].Children()
                .Cast<JProperty>()
                .Select(x => new { 
                    Title = (string)x.Value["title"] ,
                    Author = (string)x.Value["author"],
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it the same way you did before. You just have to modify your entity class to something like this:

```
public class MyVeryVeryUsefulObject
{

    public Position[] position { get; set; }
    public string baz { get; set; }
    public string quxx { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public Int32[] top;
    public Int32[] middle;
    public Int32[] bottom;
}
```

And so on. You just have to represent the JSON-Objects as Entity Classes within your code.

I have found a useful link some time ago, maybe this would reduce your workload from realizing this json structure.
http://json2csharp.com/